# (re)setting ip range for k8 loadBalancerIP assignments

Tags: kubernetes

When I created a given k8 cluster I didn't specify anything specific for **service-cluster-ip-range**. Now when I create new **loadBalancer** services k8 is assigning values that walk on existing ip addresses within the network.

Checking the allowed range via `kubectl cluster-info dump  | grep service-cluster-ip-range` gives me:

```
"--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12"
```

which (oddly enough) isn't where the assigned values are coming from. New values seem to have started at 10.95.96.235 and incremented from there.

Attempts to preset a valid ip in a service descriptor via **spec.loadBalancerIP** gives me errors from kubelet:

```
Failed to allocate IP for "newservice": "10.95.96.233" is not allowed in config
```

My questions are:

- is it possible to change **service-cluster-ip-range** without rebuilding the entire cluster?
- if not, do I have any other options for (pre)setting **loadBalancerIP** ?

Comment: How did you install the cluster?

Comment: kubeadm with lots of defaults

Comment: spec.loadBalancerIP should not be from --service-cluster-ip-range because it is not the ClusterIP. Load balancer is different thing than ClusterIP Service. How did you set up the Load Balancer?